# Showing that a sum of a function and its partial derivative is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

$$S=\left\{ f\in C'(r)\mid df+e\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec n} = 0 \text{ on the boundary } \partial r \right\}$$

$d$ and $e$ are constants

How does one show that this is a subspace?
Would one integrate the partial derivative to find an expression for f getting a sum of $\frac {1}{2} df^2 + ef + \text{constant}$ or treat f and the partial derivative as two different functions?

So this is a subspace only if the sum in the original expression is equal to zero?

Comment: How do you show that a given set is a subspace? Hint: Consider the linear map $L = \textrm{d} + e \frac{\partial }{\partial n}$.